# Changing layout files of external libraries

Tags: android

I have discovered that you are allowed to change XML layout files belonging to external libraries. I did this in order for the libs to better suit my app. Earlier today I have tried implementing firebase in my app, and for some reason that broke everything. Now, the libraries I use no longer conform to the edited versions of their layouts. This might have to do with the fact that I have also invalidated the caches. Anyhow, while looking at the libaries' layouts' contents (by browsing via project view), the changes I have made are still there, but they are simply not reflected in the app. Why is this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The way to get it working again is to delete/reimport the affected libraries from gradle and make the layout changes again